# Problem with dash using XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, line-breaking, koma-script, hyphenation

I am writting with LaTeX my bachelor thesis. 
I am using XeLaTeX because you can easily highlight text with the `xesearch` package.

My problem is that words with a dash like **HTML-Request** are not broken properly.
In the PDF file there are two dashes at the end of the line.

I suppose the problem is the usage of `\UndoBoundary{-}`. I am using it because otherwise notionssuch as **Web-Verifier** won't be highlighted.

Could you help me, please?

I post the full head maybe you could give me some other hints, too.
I am using KomaScript.

```
%\documentclass[a4paper, twoside,12pt,abstracton,parskip=half]{scrreprt}
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,abstracton,parskip=half]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}

\usepackage[german=quotes]{csquotes}

\MakeOuterQuote{"}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{extsizes}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{xesearch}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{titleref}

\usepackage[textwidth=16cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{xcolor}


\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Arial}


%\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=numeric,
sortlocale=de_DE,
natbib=true,
url=false, 
doi=true,
eprint=false
]{biblatex}

\usepackage[automark,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\clearpairofpagestyles
\cfoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\lehead{\headmark}
\rohead{\headmark}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}


\addbibresource{citations.bib}

\UndoBoundary{-}
\SearchList{i4}{\textit{#1}}{Web-Verifier}
\SearchList{i5}{\textit{#1}}{Web-Verifiers}
\SearchList{i6}{\textit{#1}}{Single Page Web Application}

%\SearchList{i8}{\textit{#1}}{}
%\SearchList{i9}{\textit{#1}}{}


\hyphenation{Web-Verifier}
\hyphenation{Web-Verifiers}


\newcounter{savepage}
\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{abstract}
\thispagestyle{plain}
Web-Verifier HTTP-Request HTTP-Response HTTP-Request HTTP-Response HTTP-Request HTTP-Response
HTTP-Request HTTP-Response HTTP-Request HTTP-Response HTTP-Request HTTP-Response
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT:**

I commented `\UndoBoundary{-}` and `\SearchList` out. The dash at the end of the line works as expected, now.

But I would like to highlight words with dashes (e.g. Web-Verifier) in my document with `\SearchList`.

Could anybody help me with this problem?

PS: @admins Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: An example of text producing the issue is needed.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I added an example which show the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a working solution for me. It's probably not the best.
I use the package `hyphenat` and replace the dash in words, which should not be highlighted, with \hyp{}.

Now it looks like this:

```
%\documentclass[a4paper, twoside,12pt,abstracton,parskip=half]{scrreprt}
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,abstracton,parskip=half]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}


\MakeOuterQuote{"}

\usepackage{extsizes}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{xesearch}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{titleref}

\usepackage{hyphenat}

\usepackage[textwidth=13cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{xcolor}


\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Arial}

\usepackage[automark,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\clearpairofpagestyles
\cfoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\lehead{\headmark}
\rohead{\headmark}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}


\UndoBoundary{-}
\SearchList{i4}{\textit{#1}}{Web-Verifier}
\SearchList{i5}{\textit{#1}}{Web-Verifiers}
\SearchList{i6}{\textit{#1}}{Single Page Web Application}

\newcounter{savepage}
\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{abstract}
\thispagestyle{plain}
Web-Verifier HTTP\hyp{}Request HTTP\hyp{}Response HTTP\hyp{}Request HTTP\hyp{}Response HTTP\hyp{}Request HTTP\hyp{}Response
HTTP\hyp{}Request HTTP\hyp{}Response HTTP\hyp{}Request HTTP\hyp{}Response HTTP\hyp{}Request HTTP\hyp{}Response
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```